# Foreign Key definitions on Sequelize Models

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create Sequelize (3.20) models of these 2 tables on Postgresql:

```
| user  |          | comment  |
|-------|          |----------|
| id    |          | id       |
| email |          | userId   |
```

*user* table is on *crm* schema and *comment* table is on *comment* schema. `comment.userId` has foreign key to `user.id`.

```
var User = db_conn.define('user', {
  email: {
    ...
  }
}, {
  ...
});
User.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
  return User.create({
    email: 'mail@gmail.com'
  });
});

var Comment = db_conn.define('comment', {
  userId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
        model: User,
        key  : 'id',
        deferrable: Sequelize.Deferrable.INITIALLY_DEFERRED
    }
  }
}, {
  ...
});
Comment.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
  return Comment.create({
    userId: 1,
  });
});
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "user" does not exist
```

Generated SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "comment"."comment" ("id"   SERIAL, "userID" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
```

As you see it's creating a FK to `user` table not `'crm'.'user'` table. And it's cauisng error because there is no *user* table on public schema. Can you please tell me what is I'm missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround until Sequelize has this issue fixed, you could set the search_path of the user you're logging in to the database with, as follows:

```
ALTER ROLE sequelize_user IN DATABASE my_sequelize_app_db
  SET search_path = crm, comment, public;
```

That way, the CREATE TABLE statement that's currently failing will work nicely. You would only run into problems if you have tables with same name on different schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using this code:

```
var Comment = db_conn.define('comment', {
  userId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: 'user',
    referencesKey: 'userId'
    }
  }
}
```

It is important that the 'references'-attribute has the exact same name as the table-name in your database (mind the capitalisation!)

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Same error @Simon . Also getting *deprecated* error

Answer (score -1):

Sequelize doesn't support cross database joins at the moment. the guys here has suggest a hack to achieve it. Please check.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3023

Comment: It's not cross database. All these schemas on same databases.